# check constraint not working as per the condition defined in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table  `aa(id int, sdate date, edate date, constraint chk check(sdate<= enddate)`. For a particular id I have to check for overlapping dates. That is I do not want any one to insert data of a perticular id which has overlapping dates. So i need to check the below conditions -

1. if @id = id and (@sdate >= edate or @edate <= sdate) then allow insert
2. if @id = id and (@sdate < edate or @edate > sdate) then do not allow insert
3. if @id <> id then allow inserts

I have encapsulated the above logic in a function and used that function in check constraint. Function is working fine but check constraint is not allowing me to enter any records. I do not know why - my function and constraint are mentioned below :

```
alter function fn_aa(@id int,@sdate date,@edate date)
returns int
as
begin
declare @i int
if exists (select * from aa where id = @id and (@sdate >= edate or @edate <= sdate)) or not exists(select * from aa where id = @id)
begin
set @i = 1
end
if exists(select * from aa where id = @id and (@sdate < edate or @edate < sdate)) 
begin
set @i = 0
end
return @i
end

go

alter table aa
add constraint aa_ck check(dbo.fn_aa(id,sdate,edate) = 1)
```

Now when I try to insert any value in the table aa I get the following error -

"Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "aa_ck". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.aa".
The statement has been terminated."

Function is returning value 1 but constraint is not allowing to insert data. Can some one help me here. I am trying for last 2 hours but cannot understand what am i doing wrong?

-

Comment: The constraint check *after* you insert the row into the table, so it is always fail. You may add an unique index on `id`, `sdate` to avoid checking the row itself, as it is already guard by the index before the constraints.

Comment: I just added identity column to the table and changed the constraint to - alter table aa
add constraint aa_ck check(dbo.fn_aa(id,sdate,edate) = 1 and id1 <> scope_identity()) - But I am still getting the same error

Comment: i need someone to guide me how to make constraint check that it is not checking the current row inserted

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is wrong.  Two rows overlap

```
alter function fn_aa(@id int,@sdate date,@edate date)
returns int
as
begin
    if exists (select *
               from aa
               where id = @id and
                     @sdate < edate and @edate > sdate
              )
    begin
        return 0;
    end;
    return 1;
end;
```

Your version would return 1 when either of these conditions is true:  `@sdate >= edate` or `@edate <= sdate`.  However, checking for an overlap depends on both end points.

Comment: Appologies.. I forgot to add another check constraint which checks that startdate < enddate. When this logic is applied we do not need to check for both the ends. I will update my question.

Comment: @sam . . . That doesn't change my answer.